# Остановка loop в асинхронном скрипте

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, asyncio

возможно дубликат вопроса, но ответа на свой вопрос я не нашёл.
У меня есть софт на pyqt5, в котором по кнопке я запускаю и останавливаю (должен останавливать) асинхронный скрипт.
*Дело в том что при попытке остановить, софт не останавливается а просто зависает.
Без понятия как остановить скрипт.

Код в софте (**`main.py`**):

```
self.check.clicked.connect(self.start_check) #подключаю кнопку к функции

def start_check(self):
    if self.check.isChecked():
         self.check_ss() #функция запуска скрипта
    else:
         self.stop_checking() #функция остановки скрипта

def check_ss(self):
    match gate:
        case 0:
            self.authorizeone = Authorize_One()
            with open(cc_base, 'r+') as f:
                ss = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
                for s in ss: #цикл который по списку отправляет данные в асинхронный скрипт
                    self.authorizeone.run(ss=s)

def stop_checking(self):
    self.authorizeone = Authorize_One() #инициализация класса из асинхронного файла
    self.authorizeone.stop_check() #вызов функции с файла
```

Код в асинхронном скрипте (**`check.py`**):

```
def run(self, ss: str=None):
    global loop
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(self.check(ss))

def stop_check(self):
    #loop.stop()
    print('Stopped')
```

Comment: А чем остановка отличается от зависания ? И главное, где в вашем скрипте хоть что то асинхронное. Я что то не наблюдаю ни одного async/await а без них все синхронно

Comment: @Mike в скрипте только 1 асинхронная функция просто с запросами через aiohttp но она очень длинная и не поместилась бы сюда

Comment: А каким образом у вас stop_check() вызывается ? оно в каком потоке работает ? Если в том же, что и asyncio то оно никогда не получит управление, пока не завершиться run_until_complete() а он видимо не завершиться пока вы stop не дадите ... А если в другом, то там надо принимать специальные меры вроде как тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133630/stopping-asyncio-in-thread

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)